# Trying to hook into a dll (I think)

Tags: c#

I'm working on a challenging hobby project involving automotive tuning software and data acquisition. The software I'm using supports the connection of an 8-channel 0-5V data acquisition module known as the DLP-IO8 which is equipped with a genuine FTDI FT232R chip. This module allows me to connect external sensors to enhance vehicle data logging capabilities.

My specific goal is to connect a non-supported serial device to the tuning software.

In an attempt to tackle this challenge, I've developed a simple WinForms application that establishes connections to both the DLP-IO8 module and the 3rd party sensor through serial connections. Fortunately, I've been successful in reading data streams from both sources. My idea is to replace 1 of the DLP-IO8 channels data stream and insert the 3rd parties sensor data in it's place. This part is fine.

However, a significant hurdle has emerged. Initially, I thought creating a virtual COM port pair and having my app respond to the tuning software's DLP-IO8 requests would work. Unfortunately, it's not as straightforward as I initially thought.

I've discovered that the tuning software references the FTDI FTD2XX_NET.dll, and I'm exploring ways to intercept the software's calls to functions within this DLL. Upon inspection of the FTD2XX_NET.dll and through trial and error I have isolated the tuning software's most minimal software requirements as a basic implementation below:

```
using FTD2XX_NET;

namespace D2XXAccess
{
    public class D2XXAccess 
    {
        public void DetectDLPDevice()
        {
            FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;
            UInt32 ftdiDeviceCount = 0;
            FTDI myFtdiDevice = new FTDI();
            bool deviceFound = false;

            // number of ftdi devices
            ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftdiDeviceCount);
            
            // Check status ok and number of devices > 0
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK || ftdiDeviceCount == 0)
            {
                return; // throw exception
            }

            // Allocate storage for device info list
            FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] ftdiDeviceList = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[ftdiDeviceCount];

            // Populate our device list
            ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetDeviceList(ftdiDeviceList);

            if (ftStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                // Check each device for the description term DLP-IO8
                for (int i = 0; i < ftdiDeviceList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ftdiDeviceList[i]?.Description == "DLP-IO8")
                    {
                        deviceFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!deviceFound)
                {
                    return; // throw exception
                }
            }
            // ftStatus not ok!
            else 
            {
                return; // throw exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In essence, I'm seeking guidance on how to intercept the tuning software's interactions with the FTD2XX_NET.dll. My goal is to make my app act as a DLP-IO8 without the need for a physical DLP-IO8 device, effectively emulating its functionality. Search results like DLL injection and API hooking have come up, but they seem overwhelming and foreign to me at this stage. I'm hoping for expert advice to navigate this complex endeavor?